# Javascript onchange not catching on drop box change

Tags: javascript, onchange

OK I am attempting to use onchange to capture the value from a dropbx but while I select the the value in the box it never seems to catch the onchange and I get an undefined value for the variable I try and capture the change with. I popped print statement into the onchange function call and it never seems to pick up the value switch. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
newWindow = window.open("", null, "height=400,width=800,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");

newWindow.document.title = "Crafting Window";
newWindow.document.body.style.background = "#00214D";
newWindow.document.body.style.color = "White";

// create a form and set properties
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.method = 'post';

// insert into the body of the new window
newWindow.document.body.appendChild(form);

// add text before the input
var cNumLab = document.createElement('cNumLab');
form.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Craft Number:'));

// add a text input
var cNum = document.createElement('input');
cNum.type = 'text';
cNum.name = 'input';
cNum.value = '';
form.appendChild(cNum);

//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
form.appendChild(linebreak);

// add text before the input
var sDescL = document.createElement('sDescL');
form.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Short Desc:'));

// add a text input
var sDesc = document.createElement('input');
sDesc.type = 'text';
sDesc.name = 'sDesc';
sDesc.value = '';
sDesc.size = 50;
form.appendChild(sDesc);

//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
form.appendChild(linebreak);

// add text before the input
var lDescL = document.createElement('lDesc');
form.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Long Desc:'));

// add a text input
var lDesc = document.createElement('input');
lDesc.type = 'text';
lDesc.name = 'lDesc';
lDesc.value = '';
lDesc.size = 80;
form.appendChild(lDesc);

//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
form.appendChild(linebreak);

// add text before the input
var eDescL = document.createElement('eDescL');
form.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Extended Desc:'));

//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
form.appendChild(linebreak);

// add a text input
var eDesc = document.createElement('textarea');
eDesc.type = 'text';
eDesc.name = 'eDesc';
eDesc.value = '';
form.appendChild(eDesc);

//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
form.appendChild(linebreak);

// add text before the input
var eTools = document.createElement('eTools');
form.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Tools:'));

// add a text input
var eTool = document.createElement('input');
eTool.type = 'text';
eTool.name = 'eTools';
eTool.value = '';
form.appendChild(eTool);


var tools = document.createElement('select');
tools.id = 'sTools';
tools.name = 'sTools';
form.appendChild(tools);

var cTool;
var e = document.getElementById("sTools");
var options = [
    ["Forge 33", "33"],
    ["Workbench 1391", "1391"],
    ["Oven 1753", "1753"],
    ["Mortar-Pestle 3277", "3277"],
    ["Chisel 3349", "3349"],
    ["Pottery Wheel 3420", "3420"],
    ["Kiln 3421", "3421"],
    ["Blowpipe3422", "3422"],
    ["Bookbinder 3467", "3467"],
    ["Palette 3483", "3483"]
];

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(options[i][0]));
    opt.value = options[i][1];
    tools.appendChild(opt);
}

tools.onchange = function () {
    print("GOT HERE");
    cTool = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(cTool);
};

//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
form.appendChild(linebreak);

// add text before the input
var eIngreds = document.createElement('eIngreds');
form.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Ingredients:'));

// add a text input
var eIngred = document.createElement('input');
eIngred.type = 'text';
eIngred.name = 'eIngred';
eIngred.value = '';
eIngred.size = 50;
form.appendChild(eIngred);


//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
form.appendChild(linebreak);

// add text before the input
var eSteps1 = document.createElement('eSteps1');
form.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Step 1:'));

// add a text input
var eStep1 = document.createElement('input');
eStep1.type = 'text';
eStep1.name = 'eStep1';
eStep1.value = '';
eStep1.size = 80;
form.appendChild(eStep1);

//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
form.appendChild(linebreak);

// add text before the input
var eSteps1 = document.createElement('eSteps2');
form.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Step 2:'));

// add a text input
var eStep2 = document.createElement('input');
eStep2.type = 'text';
eStep2.name = 'eStep2';
eStep2.value = '';
eStep2.size = 80;
form.appendChild(eStep2);

//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
form.appendChild(linebreak);

// add text before the input
var eSteps3 = document.createElement('eSteps3');
form.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Step 3:'));

// add a text input
var eStep3 = document.createElement('input');
eStep3.type = 'text';
eStep3.name = 'eStep3';
eStep3.value = '';
eStep3.size = 80;
form.appendChild(eStep3);

//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
form.appendChild(linebreak);

// add text before the input
var eSteps4 = document.createElement('eSteps4');
form.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Step 4:'));

// add a text input
var eStep4 = document.createElement('input');
eStep4.type = 'text';
eStep4.name = 'eStep4';
eStep4.value = '';
eStep4.size = 80;
form.appendChild(eStep4);

//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
form.appendChild(linebreak);

// add text before the input
var eSteps5 = document.createElement('eSteps5');
form.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Step 5:'));

// add a text input
var eStep5 = document.createElement('input');
eStep5.type = 'text';
eStep5.name = 'eStep5';
eStep5.value = '';
eStep5.size = 80;
form.appendChild(eStep5);

//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
form.appendChild(linebreak);

// add text before the input
var eSteps6 = document.createElement('eSteps6');
form.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Step 6:'));

// add a text input
var eStep6 = document.createElement('input');
eStep6.type = 'text';
eStep6.name = 'eStep6';
eStep6.value = '';
eStep6.size = 80;
form.appendChild(eStep6);

var cTool;
var e = document.getElementById("sTools");

tools.onchange = function () {
    cTool = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(cTool);

};

//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
form.appendChild(linebreak);

var eSubmit = document.createElement('button');
eSubmit.type = 'button';
//eSubmit.name = 'Submit Design';
eSubmit.innerHTML = 'Submit Design';
eSubmit.onclick = function () {

    if (sDesc.value !== "") {
        client.send_direct("craft edit " + cNum.value + " short_desc " + sDesc.value);
    }
    if (lDesc.value !== "") {
        client.send_direct("craft edit " + cNum.value + " long_desc " + lDesc.value);
    }
    if (eDesc.value !== "") {
        client.send_direct("craft edit " + cNum.value + " extended_desc " + eDesc.value);
    }
    if (eIngred.value !== "") {
        client.send_direct("craft ingredients " + cNum.value + "  " + eIngred.value);
    }
    if (eTool.value !== "") {
        client.send_direct("craft tools " + cNum.value + " add " + eTool.value);
    }
    if (eStep1.value !== "") {
        client.send_direct("craft steps " + cNum.value + " change 1 1 " + eStep1.value);
    }
    if (eStep2.value !== "") {
        client.send_direct("craft steps " + cNum.value + " change 2 1 " + eStep2.value);
    }
    if (eStep3.value !== "") {
        client.send_direct("craft steps " + cNum.value + " change 3 1 " + eStep3.value);
    }
    if (eStep4.value !== "") {
        client.send_direct("craft steps " + cNum.value + " change 4 1 " + eStep4.value);
    }
    if (eStep5.value !== "") {
        client.send_direct("craft steps " + cNum.value + " change 5 1 " + eStep5.value);
    }
    if (eStep6.value !== "") {
        client.send_direct("craft steps " + cNum.value + " change 6 1 " + eStep6.value);
    }
    alert(cTool);
};
form.appendChild(eSubmit);
```

Comment: Whittle your code down to the code/problem in question. Also...is there a reason for not using Jquery?? Because all that code could be a few lines if you did

Comment: OK Last time I posted just the subset it worked fine and was told to post the whole form. Also I'm not familar with JQuery. I am just relearning JavaScript. I'll take a look thanks!

Comment: @Kylek Is there a reason of why using jquery? I don't think so. He can use jquery or not, that doesn't matter for the question been asked

Comment: @Juan  You're right, its not relevant to the question, but this site is about helping others, and passing on knowledge.  I couldn't imagine using plain old javascript anymore for any sort of DOM manipulation or AJAX.  Plus Jquery has cross browser baked in.  Its a win win.

Comment: @KyleK I do. And I don't find myself in any situation where I need jquery. I think is fine for people who use it. A good code plain js is better than a poorly coded jquery and viceversa. It is just a choice, and the OP has chosen plain js

Comment: Maybe a jsfiddle link would be nice. :)

Comment: @user3763307 Your specific problem it is hard to find. I'll point out a few things however. You are setting twice onchange property, the second assignment will cancel the first one. You are reasigning e variable, I'm not sure why are you reading options property from e... You shouldn't use onchange and event listeners should be used instead. I'll recommend you to declare once all your variable first, learn about scopes and better ways of structuring your code, copy/paste is not a good approach, learn what asynchronous calls are...

Comment: @user3763307 and btw, where did 'print' came from? It looks to me like and ReferenceError right there

Comment: Sorry old habit on the print meant to be an alert. I pulled the second onchange and didn't impact onchange firing properly.